# Fusion chart set y axis with min value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, fusioncharts

I want to hide -2k from fusion chart. (http://prntscr.com/pnhi3i)

All values in fusion chart is greater or equal to 0 but still showing the -2k so i need to set min value for y axis.

I try with : yAxisMinValue : '0'

This is my dataset :

```
dataset: [
{
  data: [
    {
      value: "50"
    },
    {
      value: "9000"
    },
    {
      value: "49"
    },
    {
      value: "22"
    },
    {
      value: "43"
    },
    {
      value: "14"
    },
    {
      value: "0"
    }
  ]
}
]
```

But it's still showing -2k.

this is chart object :

```
chart: {
        caption: "Support Tickets : Received vs Resolved",
        yaxisname: "# of Tickets",
        subcaption: "Last week",
        numdivlines: "3",
        showvalues: "0",
        legenditemfontsize: "15",
        legenditemfontbold: "1",
        plottooltext: "<b>$dataValue</b> Tickets $seriesName on $label",
        theme: "fusion",
        showVZeroPlane: "1",
        yAxisMinValue : '0',
      },
```

Would you please help me to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: set minimizeTendency as 1 at the chart level, here is a demo  -http://jsfiddle.net/vx045r1t/

Comment: Yes,it's working like charm. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can set minimizeTendency:'1' to hide the values

This attribute, when set to 1, draws splines with a low tendency factor. This is required when splines are used to connect multiple data points having the same value. While the traditional spline is perfect mathematically and by definition, the low tendency factor spline is not.

To know more about it click [here](https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-attributes/spline)

```
    FusionCharts.ready(function() {
  var visitChart = new FusionCharts({
    type: 'msspline',
    renderAt: 'chart-container',
    width: '700',
    height: '400',
    dataFormat: 'json',
    dataSource: {
      chart: {
        caption: "Support Tickets : Received vs Resolved",
        yaxisname: "# of Tickets",
        subcaption: "Last week",
        numdivlines: "3",
        showvalues: "0",
        legenditemfontsize: "15",
        legenditemfontbold: "1",
        plottooltext: "<b>$dataValue</b> Tickets $seriesName on $label",
        theme: "fusion",
        yAxisMinValue: '0',
        minimizeTendency:'1'
      },
      "categories": [{
        "category": [{
            "label": "Mon"
          },
          {
            "label": "Tue"
          },
          {
            "label": "Wed"
          },
          {
            "vline": "true",
            "lineposition": "0",
            "color": "#F2726F",
            "labelHAlign": "right",
            "labelPosition": "0",
            "label": "National holiday"
          },
          {
            "label": "Thu"
          },
          {
            "label": "Fri"
          },
          {
            "label": "Sat"
          },
          {
            "label": "Sun"
          }
        ]
      }],

      dataset: [{
        data: [{
            value: "50"
          },
          {
            value: "9000"
          },
          {
            value: "49"
          },
          {
            value: "22"
          },
          {
            value: "43"
          },
          {
            value: "14"
          },
          {
            value: "0"
          }
        ]
      }]
    }
  }).render();
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xw1orL6y/)